# translation for Strength, love and courage to Latin

Tags: vocabulary, english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, meaning, word-choice

I would like to engrave a piece in Latin for my teenage son with our “family motto.” The motto is strength, love and courage. He is studying Latin and I want to be sure the word choice is accurate. The intended meaning is to be one of/with strength (of character, body, and mind), love, and courage.

I have researched and found the words (to be engraved in capitals):

VIRTVS * AMOR * FORTITVDO

1. Could someone please tell me if these are an accurate translation and representation of the intended meaning? I am plan to have three words verses a phrase.
2. Are virtus and fortitudo redundant?  I understand virtus to be of moral, mental strength and bravery and fortitudo to be of physical strength and courage.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The words are generally suitable. **virtus** can indeed mean *strength of character, body and mind*, **amor** is indeed *love*, and **fortitudo** can mean *courage*. However, you are right that **virtus** and **fortitudo** overlap more than the corresponding English words *strength* and *courage* do. If you want a word meaning only *courage*, you could use **audacia**, but be aware that this also has negative connotations. If you want a word meaning only *strength*, you could use **firmitas**, but that means more the ability to endure than the kind of strength you are likely aiming for.